# Which graduate programs, if any, specialize in or at least explore metamodernism?

Tags: continental-philosophy

I was enthralled with this subject matter in my undergraduate studies and would like to pursue it further. Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend to pose this question on https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoWehler Please don't ask people to post places where you aren't familiar with the rules; this is blatantly off topic on Academia.